# Validate Phone Number and Country Code combination for phone number validition in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, phone-number

In my angular 4 application, I have a dropdown for Country Code and a Text Field for Phone Number.

Now, I want to check whether the given phone number is valid within the domain covered by the Country Code.

That means, If the user selectes the following:

```
countryCode: +91,
phoneNumber: 98784841110
```

I want to verify whether the country code and phone number are valid as a combination.

I also have the country names and ShortCodes if needed, basically, an element of the array I populate my country code dropdown looks are follows:

```
{
"shortCode": "GB",
"dialCode": "44",
"name": "United Kingdom"
},
```

So how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use this plugin.
https://github.com/webcat12345/ngx-intl-tel-input

Comment: My application has a countries dropdown, when user selects a value, the country code is auto-selected on basis of that, but the user can change it. How can I that with this plugin?